# "Real": adjective or adverb? "Real" or "really" as an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

According to Oxford Learner's Dictionary:

> **real** *adverb*
>
> *(North American English, Scottish English, informal)* very
>
> - *That tastes real good.*
> - *He's a real nice guy.*
> - *I'm real sorry.*

**So, is it correct to use "really" instead of "real" in the examples above?**

Now, let's put some other examples:

> a. *It's a real small town*
>
> b. *It's a really small town*
>
> c. *It's really a small town*

**Are all these three correct? Do they mean the same?**

Comment: Are you using them in an informal way? The adverbial use of "real" is really annoying to me... so I don't think it's appropriate to use it, ever... that doesn't prevent people from doing so.

Comment: In my family, "real" as an adverb is very bogan. I have to agree with @Catija.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with everything @Roy C. has said but wanted to add a comment (but am unable to as my reputation has just dipped below 50 for some reason!)

In your examples, I would read 'c. It's really a small town.' as being grammatically correct but meaning something different to b.

'It's a really small town.' --> 'It is a *very* small town.'
'It's really a small town.' --> '*In reality*, it's a small town.'

Comment: Then there is also "It really _is_ a small town".

Comment: Absolutely! :-)